# How to stop Guard from creating monstrous space consuming log files

Tags: ruby, linux, jekyll, guard

im using [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) and by the time using it i get a monstrous log with 15gb in the following paths:

- `/var/log/kern.log.1`
- `/var/log/syslog.1`

By the end of the day i have to delete this files so my machine can work in peace.
My question is how to stop guard from creating this log files??

Im using ubuntu linux and running a jekyll server

Comment: You can use [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the settings as described [here](https://github.com/guard/guard#logger) so that guard only logs on `:error` with something like in addition you could use only or except to give you nothing actually being created:

```
logger level: :error,
       only: []
```

However, as pointed out by fotanus, [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) is the standard way of dealing with these logfiles and the way I would go about adressing the problem.

There [are several](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/) [different](http://linuxers.org/howto/howto-use-logrotate-manage-log-files) [tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-manage-log-files-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-12-10) on how to use this to help manage your logging.